# How to import multiple components from one general folder?

Tags: reactjs

I have many components in a `components` folder. How can I import 
them in one line?

For example I have this:

```
import FormField from "./../components/FormField";
import MultiSelect from "./../components/MultiSelect";
```

but I want to import it like this:

```
import {MultiSelect, FormField} from "./../components";
```

which is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do like this:

```
import { MultiSelect, FormField } from "./../components";
```

In your `components` folder, create new file: `index.js` with

```
export { default as FormField } from './FormField';
export { default as MultiSelect} from './MultiSelect';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make index.js in components folder

```
export * from './FormField';
export * from './MultiSelect';
```

After this you can easily access.

```
import {MultiSelect,FormField} from "./../components";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `index.js` in components folder having:

```
export { default as FormField } from './FormField';
export { default as MultiSelect } from './MultiSelect';
```

Then in the file where you want to use these components, import them using:

```
import { MultiSelect,FormField } from "./../components";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer for your question. But let me add my 5 cents:

## First:

you may import like this: `from "../components";` instead of `from "./../components";`

## Second:

I have some experience with imports and I have found out that `import {MultiSelect, FormField} from "./../components";` has a lot of pitfalls. You need to create index.js fiels. When you will search `MultiSelect` uses within your IDE you will always have `index.js` and that isn't useful. Also if you'll decide to move your file you will have to change 3 files instead of 1 (old `index.js` new `index.js` and file that used your `MultiSelect`).

Is it worth it? It's up too you of course! But now you know what problems you may have :)